# How can I disable TLS when running from Docker?

Tags: docker, caddy

I'm using BlackGlory's *caddy-proxy*, a containerized version of the Caddy reverse-proxy, which can direct requests to my containers by merely having me label them properly.

by default Caddy attempts a TLS, which is done on a privileged port (443).  on my OSX environment this fails and I would therefore like to turn it off.  Caddy allows turning TLS off but I can't seem to get to the Caddyfile to do it (and there doesn't seem to be a parameter to do this).

here's a transcript of my efforts: https://github.com/BlackGlory/caddy-proxy/issues/9

can anyone suggest how I could get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

in your caddyfile add the below for your site

```
tls no
```

Comment: that is valid only on a per-site basis.  the question concerns how to turn it off completely (in all cases)

Comment: in case someone reaches here recently, https://github.com/caddyserver/caddy/pull/3284